# LIS code giving error in python

Tags: python

I am writing this longest increasing sub-sequence code in Python but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    if s[j]<s[i] and len(l[i])<len(l[j])+1 :
Index Error: list index out of range
```

i was previously getting this same error. Is there any error in my style of writing the code?

```
n=int(raw_input())
s=map(int,raw_input().split())
l=[]
l.append([]*1000)
l[0].append(s[0])
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i):
        if s[j]<s[i] and len(l[i])<len(l[j])+1 :
            l[i]=l[j]
    l[i].append(s[i])
lo=0
for x in l:
    if lo<len(x):
        lo=len(x)
print lo
```

Comment: Do you know which of those indexes is failing? What `i` and `j` are when it fails? What is in `s` and `l` when it fails?

Comment: s is the array we are given. l stores the no of sequences

Comment: No, I mean you should go and find out (`print`?) what those values are when it fails and whether the lists contain what you expected or not. That is debugging 101.

Comment: thnx.. ill do it  :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the list you multiplied. Since it is empty, it remains empty.

```
In [3]: [] * 1000
Out[3]: []
```

If you wanted 1000 empty lists, instead of

```
l=[]
l.append([]*1000)
```

you could do for example

```
l = [[] for _ in xrange(1000)]
```

There might be other issues in the code, but this is the first one and should handled first.

About the code style, use many more spaces. Go over [PEP-8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more details. As a first, put spaces around the "="s to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: It gives an error in the same location or a different one? That one is definitely a bug, there might be others. I edited the comment to add some detail about code style. Hope this helps!